# Rearrange columns separated by : in LINUX

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

The question is how to rearrange the column along with values in desired order.

input

```
"a":"val1","c":"val2","b":"val3","d":"val4"
"a":"val1","b":[],"c":"val3","d":"val4"
"a":"val1","d":["val2","val32],"c":"val3","b":"val4"
"d":"val1","a":"val2","c":"val3","b":"val4"
```

Expected output should be in a,b,c,d and their corresponding values.

```
"a":"val1"|"b":"val3"|"c":"val2"|"d":"val4"
"a":"val1"|"b":[]|"c":"val3"|"d":"val4"
"a":"val1"|"b":"val4"|"c":"val3"|"d":["val2","val32]
"a":"val2"|"b":"val4"|"c":"val3"|"d":"val1"
```

Comment: The `_idx` column in your script is `$1` and not `$2` (could it be _that_ simple ? )

Comment: (1) Could you possibly present your problem using input that isn’t soooo loooong that it needs to be scrolled horizontally?  (2) Please give an example of the desired output.  (3) Please explain the logic of your attempt(s).  For example, I see a `sed` command that is inserting newlines into the data immediately followed by a `tr` command that is removing newlines.  That doesn’t make any sense.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: May you please make it clear if double quotes have to be stripped in the final output? Also, are your columns allowed to contain the `<space>,` column separator, e.g. `"idxg_name":"something ,else"`?

Comment: Now you have apparently left out the sample of your input data (it looks like you are showing the expected output (thanks!) and then only the data at an intermediate step). And _please_ try to stop changing the format of your desired output, it makes harder for others to work on an answer.

Comment: could you add a stable sample of input/desired ouput/and current output. Finally if it is json, please use json tool for it.

Comment: On the one hand, this seems to be a lot cleaner and clearer than it was yesterday.   I guess that the first 12 lines are supposed to be the definitive, normative example of input and associated output.   It’s good; it’s simple enough to be understandable, but complex enough to illustrate the manipulations that need to be performed.   On the other hand, it’s frustrating that (as @fra-san pointed out), you show the expected output for a somewhat less simple example (closer to your real data / what you presented in the first version of the question), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and three intermediate results (from your process, which, apparently, doesn’t work correctly, and which hasn’t been explained), ***but not the input file!***  Also (as @fra-san pointed out), lines 9-12 show the quotes being left alone, but the other examples show the quotes being removed.  It’s not clear whether you’re looking for a solution that can process your original file (the one with the >250 columns) and discard >246 of them, or are you already handling that?  And a typo: you say you have a field called `create`, but then you show a field called ``creat``.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your last edit: your sample data resembles JSON and cannot be handled as if it were simple, something-separated text. On top of what @G-Man said, my general advice would be to beware te [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/410681)—that's why we insist on asking for realistic, definitive input and output. Also, try to focus on one small problem at a time: break down complex issues into precise, self contained smaller points and dedicate a question to each of them (questions are free).

Comment: `sed -Ee 's/^/\n/' -e "$(printf 's/(.*)(^|\\n|,)("%s":(("[^"]*")|(\[[^]]*])))/\\3|\\1/;' d c b a)" -e 's/\|\n.*//' input.file` this is using Gnu sed and change a b c d to the required column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question evolved significantly over time, I'll try to address three distinct points.

#### Your attempt<sup>1</sup>

Your `awk` command is trying to split your lines on occurrences of `admin:`. Even if it made sense you would only be able to reference fields `$1` and `$2`, since you only have one occurrence of `admin:` in each of your lines.

You may be looking for something as:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '"_id":"asc" ,"name":"enygren" ,"admin":[] ,"creat":"date3"' |
  sed 's/"//g' |
  awk -F' ,' -v OFS='|' '{if ($2~/name:/){print $1,$3,$4,$2} else {$1=$1; print $0}}'
```

Which, of course, may happen not to be a good idea: `/name:/` matches anything that *contains* `name:`, not just the exact label `name:`.

Anyway, this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/410681).

---

#### Rearranging columns

Here is an `awk` solution that you can customize to select and reorder your columns, assuming they are from a [delimited text file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values).

It makes the assumption that the fields in your input data cannot contain any `"` or `,`. This sounded reasonable based on the code you posted<sup>1</sup>, but actually appears not to be the case. You should resort to some tool specialized in manipulation of structured data (see below), e.g. [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for CSV or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for JSON (thanks to [Kiwi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518120/rearrange-columns-separated-by-in-linux#comment957420_518120) for the hint).

Given the script `prog_file`:

```sh
BEGIN {
                        # Create an array of labels for the fileds you want
                        # to keep, in the order you want to print them
    labels[1] = "\"_id\""
    labels[2] = "\"admin\""
    labels[3] = "\"creat\""
    labels[4] = "\"name\""
}
{
                        # Split any field on ":" and make an array of
                        # full fields indexed by their label.
                        # This assumes labels DO NOT CONTAIN any ":"
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        split($i, chunks, ":")
        fields[chunks[1]] = $i
    }
                        # Reset the record
    $0 = ""
                        # Re-build the record with only the fields
                        # whose labels are in the array we defined in
                        # the BEGIN block.
                        # Explicitly use "4" as the upper bound because
                        # POSIX does not specify the order in which
                        # "for (var in array)" assigns indexes to var
    for ( i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
        $i = fields[labels[i]]
    }
                        # Strip any double quote
    gsub("\"","")
    print $0
}
```

and the input<sup>2</sup>:

```
"_id":"123" ,"admin":[src] ,"creat":"date1" ,"name":"dedu"
"_id":"2w3" ,"admin":[analise] ,"creat":"date2" ,"name":"csv"
"_id":"asc" ,"name":"enygren" ,"admin":[] ,"creat":"date3"
"_id":"scd" ,"admin":[] ,"creat":"date4" ,"name":"tzpi"
```

the invocation:

```sh
awk -v FS=' ,' -v OFS='|' -f prog_file input_file
```

gives<sup>3</sup>:

```
_id:123|admin:[src]|creat:date1|name:dedu
_id:2w3|admin:[analise]|creat:date2|name:csv
_id:asc|admin:[]|creat:date3|name:enygren
_id:scd|admin:[]|creat:date4|name:tzpi
```

#### Dealing with data formats

The [last](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/518120/7) sample of input data you edited into your question does not seem to be from a delimited text file. It looks like a list of JSON objects.
Despite being human-readable, [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a *data* format and requires a different approach—indeed the above `awk` solution will not work with that input.

Adding a bit structure, your sample can be turned (back?) into valid JSON:

```sh
$ cat file
"a":"val1","c":"val2","b":"val3","d":"val4"
"a":"val1","b":[],"c":"val3","d":"val4"
"a":"val1","d":["val2","val32"],"c":"val3","b":"val4"
"d":"val1","a":"val2","c":"val3","b":"val4"
```

(Note that I assumed that a missing `"` in `"d":["val2","val32]` was a typo, and used `"d":["val2","val32"]` instead).

```sh
$ sed 's/^/{/; s/$/},/; 1 s/^/[/; $ s/,$/]/' file >tmpfile
```

```json
$ cat tmpfile 
[{"a":"val1","c":"val2","b":"val3","d":"val4"},
{"a":"val1","b":[],"c":"val3","d":"val4"},
{"a":"val1","d":["val2","val32"],"c":"val3","b":"val4"},
{"d":"val1","a":"val2","c":"val3","b":"val4"}]
```

Then, the safe approach would be to use a JSON processor as `jq` to filter and reorder your data:

```sh
$ jq -r '.[] | {a: .a, b: .b, c: .c, d: .d} | @text' tmpfile
{"a":"val1","b":"val3","c":"val2","d":"val4"}
{"a":"val1","b":[],"c":"val3","d":"val4"}
{"a":"val1","b":"val4","c":"val3","d":["val2","val32"]}
{"a":"val2","b":"val4","c":"val3","d":"val1"}
```

Removing the remaining opening and closing curly braces is trivial and safe, while *it will not be safe* to blindly remove double quotes (`"`) or replace commas with vertical bars (`,` → `|`) to fully match your sample output.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>From question's [revisions n° 4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/518120/4) to [n° 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/518120/7).</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Inferred from the last part of question's [revision n° 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/518120/6).</sub>
<sup>3</sup> <sub>From question's [revision n° 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/518120/6).</sub>

Comment: I applaud your patience (chasing the moving target through smoke and fog). If the question had ever stabilized enough for me to consider it to be answerable, I probably would have written something similar to your ```awk``` answer (extracting the desired values into an associative array, and then outputting them in the desired order).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if I ignore your attempt. It looks too complicated to me, piping through many scripts and tools.

As I understand, the columns are in correct order, except for the `idxg_name`, which should be placed at the end. So I suggest to simply do:

```
sed 's/"//g;s/\(,idxg_name:[^,]*\)\(.*\)/\2\1/' yourfile
```

- The `s/"//g` part removes the `"` like you already did
- `,idxg_name:[^,]*` matches the `idxg_name` field, starting at the comma and including everything before the next comma (note that this will fail, if the name includes a comma! If this can happen, it will make things more complicated, considering, whether the comma is inside `""`)
- The `.*` matches the rest of the line and
- the replacement `\2\1` changes the order of both parts inside those `\(\)`, thus placing the name field at the end of the line. Done.